# Windows Phone 8.1 build fails on Unity 5.2.3f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to publish our games on the Windows 8.1 store but I keep getting this error:

========

> UnityException: Platform assembly not found.
>   Make sure Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Phone SDK 8.1 is installed.
>   PostProcessWinRT.CheckSDK () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WinRT/SharedSources/CSharp/PostProcessWinRT.cs:164)
>   PostProcessWinRT.Process () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WinRT/SharedSources/CSharp/PostProcessWinRT.cs:103)
>   UnityEditor.Metro.BuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/ExtensionModule.cs:99)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

========

I have a fresh install of Windows 8.1 Enterprise. Fresh download of Unity 5.2.3f1 with the standard installer of visual studio community 2015. All windows updates applied and no other software installed on the machine. I am trying this with a fresh project.

Comment: You have to install WP 8.1 SDK.

Comment: Checked from within Visual Studio and the SDK wasn't there. Will update if unity succeeds in making the build after the sdk update.

Comment: Notice that you need VS 2013 to install WP 8.1 SDK. I think you should fallow Tiziano Coroneo's answer. He described the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to download Visual Studio 2013:

https://www.visualstudio.com/it-it/products/visual-studio-express-vs

The Express version is free.
Second, to install the Windows Phone Sdk 8.1

https://developer.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk

Then, you've got to link the path of where you've installed the sdk in the Unity Preferences.

Here you can find a full guide from the Unity guys:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-gettingstarted.html

Comment: But I already have downloaded VS 2015. Is 2013 a requirement? If so; do I need to remove 2015 or can I install 2013 side by side?

Comment: There is no need to remove VS 2015. I've got 2012, 2013 and 2015 at the same time and there is no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

According to Unity, when building for Windows Phone 8.1, Unity looks for the SDK at `H_KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\InstallationFolder`. The usual value in this place is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\`. If it is **empty** or the key does not exist, try to re-install Windows Phone 8.1 SDK and make sure that the values exist in that location. The file Unity is looking for in that folder is `References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd`. So make sure it exist.

Run **cmd**, **regedit** and search for `H_KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\InstallationFolder` location.

Comment: Theres no 8.1 folder in the location you mentioned. I have installed Phone 8.1 SDK. It has been 3 weeks and I still can't get this up and running.

I have fresh installed Unity 5.3.2f1 with VS2013. VSTools also installed as well as the SDK. Same error on different machines.

Comment: Replying to a post 12 days later means that you are not really having any problems.  If you are really having problems, find where you installed the Windows 8.1 sdk, copy the path and paste it in the registry location I posted in my answer then restart your computer.